# Как спарсить td теги

Tags: python

Пытаюсь получить актуальный курс валют

Написал вот такой код

```
link = "https://myfin.by/currency/minsk"
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.149 Safari/537.36'}

# Парсим всю страницу
full_page = requests.get(link, headers=headers).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(full_page, "html.parser")
price = soup.find_all('tr', {'class': 'tr-tb acc-link_14 not_h'})[0]
```

на выходе получил

```
<tr class="tr-tb acc-link_14 not_h" data-bank_id="14">
<td>
<span class="iconb belinvestbank"><a href="/bank/belinvestbank">Белинвестбанк</a></span>
</td>
<td>2.544</td><td>2.561</td><td>3.014</td><td>3.041</td><td>3.33</td><td>3.372</td><td>1.173</td><td>1.201</td></tr>
```

Не могу понять как спарсить содержимое  тегов?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться простыми регулярками

```
p = re.compile(r"<td>(.*?)</td>")
m = p.findall(YOUR_DATA)
print("m = {}".format(m))
```

В итоге в m у Вас будет список из значений.
Далее зная порядок можно получать значения:

```
print("Банк = {}".format(m[0]))
print("Доллар = {}".format(m[1]))
```

Comment: Как минимум, в вашем примере, поиск не должен быть жадным, т.е: `p = re.compile(r"<td>(.*)</td>")` надо заменить на `p = re.compile(r"<td>(.*?)</td>")`.

Comment: Спасибо поправил